# Adding attributes to functions from outside the functions

Tags: python

Code:

```py
def x():

    return 1

x.y = 2 

print(x())
print(x.y)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

My question is how can I add the y attribute from the function body?
And why is the y variable not suggested when I want to use it (for example, in the printing function)

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/478746). Why do you want to use attributes on a function object?

Comment: What do you mean by the `y` variable not being suggested? Do you mean by your IDE?

Comment: `how can I add the y attribute from the function body?` Have you tried just doing it? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @Fractalism I think OP wants to do something more like the `self`, but from inside a function.

Comment: Because I want the function to have an initial value, then I can use it as I want (eg for money - start $0 + the 'argument' at the end of the day)
Yes, from Pycharm

Comment: @RinguRing1 If you trying to model something that has state and does stuff with that state, you should probably use a class. That's literally what they're for :)

Comment: I know what classes are, but does that mean python is not that advanced?

Comment: @RinguRing1: _...is not that advanced_ compared to what ? Which output do you expect, can you give an example ?

Comment: @Maurice Meyer if I add a variable inside the function, I want to use it outside it

Comment: The `def` statement does not provide access to the function under definition. Function attributes are something that you rarely (if ever) need; I'm sometimes surprised they are allowed at all. Other built-in types disallow adding attributes to their instances.

Comment: Similarly, you can't access a class while it is being constructed by a `class` statement. (It's only due to the semantics of a `class` statement that names defined in the body are attached to the resulting class as attributes.)

Comment: You wouldn't *want* to define the attribute from the body of the function anyway, because you likely only want to make the assignment *once* when the function is defined, not every time you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add attributes to a function while it is being constructed by a `def` statement. The closest you can come is to have a decorator add the attribute once the function has been defined.

```
def attach(name, value):
    def decorator(f):
        setattr(f, name, value)
        return f
    return decorator


@attach('y', 2)
@attach('z', 3)
def x():
    return 1

print(x())  # 1
print(x.y)  # 2
print(x.z)  # 3
```